# How to Align the Row to the Right Within a Column Without Expanding Row Width

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to align the blue container to the right side of the Column without causing the row's width to expand. I tried `alignment: Alignment.centerRight` for container but its expanding the row's width to maxwidth. The message should be to the left side and time should be to the right.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 45),
        child: Card(
          color: messageColor,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
          elevation: 1.0,
          margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: 10.0,
                  right: 10.0,
                  top: 10.0,
                ),
                child: Text(message),
              ),
              Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0, left: 10.0),
                // alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      date,
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 13,
                        color: Colors.white60,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 5),
                    const Icon(
                      Icons.done_all,
                      size: 20,
                      color: Colors.white60,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `crossAxisAlignment` parameter of the column to `CrossAxisAlignment.end`.

Comment: fixed it by right padding to 70 and CrossAxisAlignment to end